# Dis-assamble .exe file to .asm in IDA Python

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

I have 5K .exe files from different sources like C and C++. I want to Dis-assamble them into .asm file using IDA Python. Consider this .exe file opened in IDA with text view:

[image]

I want this "Assembly" code but using Python script so that i can loop it on all exe files and save it in their respective .asm file. Anyone having a code to start-with will be a great help. Thanks!

Comment: And what did you try already? Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try looking around on Github, there are [many](https://github.com/williballenthin/python-idb) projects related to automating IDA. Check out [this](https://github.com/nlitsme/pyidbutil) and [this](https://github.com/nccgroup/idahunt).

Comment: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml - I'm not sure that it will work with free version, but there is a -B command line switch of full version 
 of IDA that automatically generates both .idb and .asm.

Answer (score 1):

Alas the Freeware version does not support IDAPython or any plugins other than those shipped with it. If you need to automate your disassembly, buy the full version.

Comment: you are saying that writing and execution of IDAPython script is not possible until i buy a pro version?